# How to insert Ruby array items into SQLite?

Tags: ruby, sqlite

I want to execute my `INSERT` strings within a Ruby file that has the following array:

```
names_arr = ["Jack", "Susan", "Peter"]
```

In the same Ruby file, I've required the SQLite3 gem and have this code:

```
names_arr.each do |each_name|
  db.execute('INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES ("#{each_name}");')
end
```

I am expecting this in my "users" table:

```
id  name
1   Jack
2   Susan
3   Peter
```

Instead, I'm getting this:

```
id  name
1   #{each_name}
2   #{each_name}
3   #{each_name}
```

It's clear I'm not interpolating properly, but I've tried a lot of different things and can't figure out where I'm wrong.

I am using SQLite3 and Ruby.

Comment: Try this `db.execute("INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES (#{each_name});"`

Comment: Double quotes for interpolation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several problems in this code:

```
names_arr.each do |each_name|
  db.execute('INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES ("#{each_name}");')
end
```

1. You're trying to use Ruby's string interpolation inside a single quoted string but string interpolation only works in double quoted strings (and heredocs, `%Q{...}` strings, regex literals, ...).
2. Standard SQL uses single quotes for string literals, not double quotes. Some databases let you get away with double quotes but it is a really bad habit to get into.
3. You shouldn't use string interpolation to build SQL anyway, you're not hacking PHP in 1999 so you should use placeholders and let the database library deal with the quoting.

The SQLite driver's [`execute`](http://rubydoc.info/github/luislavena/sqlite3-ruby/SQLite3/Database%3aexecute) understands `?` placeholders so you can say this:

```
names_arr.each do |each_name|
  db.execute('INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES (?)', each_name)
end
```

Comment: Thanks, this was most helpful! Also found this link that helped with inserting multiple columns of data with ? placeholders.

Comment: FYI, I just learned that another term for placeholders mu is using is "sanitation replacement."